# React Native runBackgroundTimer doesn't stop when stopBackgroundTimer is called

Tags: javascript, react-native, timer

I have a countdown timer for a meditation app implemented as follows

```
BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(() => {

      this.props.setMeditationLength(this.props.meditationLength - 1000)
      //stop timer when length is zero
      if (this.props.meditationLength <= 0){
          BackgroundTimer.stopBackgroundTimer();
      }
  }, 1000)
```

When `meditationLength` reaches zero, the timer doesn't stop. Additionally, I have a pause button, which is implemented as follows.

```
<Icon.Button
            name="pause"
            color={(this.state.backgroundColor) ? 'black' : 'grey'}
            size={40}
            backgroundColor="transparent"
            underlayColor="transparent"
            onPress={() => {BackgroundTimer.stopBackgroundTimer();}}>
</Icon.Button>
```

The pause button somehow stops the timer. What am I doing wrong? Is there a different way to stop the timer from within the BackgroundTimer function?

Thanks